# Packetloss on fiber connection

Tags: fiber, pfsense

I have the following setup:
Dell R720 Server with Esxi 6.5 running on it. On this esx, there is a pfsense-vm.
The first network-adapter of this host is connected to fibre-internet with a media converter.
The second adapter is connected to a LTE-router.
The pfsene is connected to this adapters.
If I select the fibre-connection as default IPv4-Gateway in the pfsense, I got up to 15% packet loss while pinging 8.8.8.8 from the pfsense shell. After switching the gateway to LTE, there is 0% loss.
If I ping my IP from the outside, I only got < 1% lost packets (7 of 2500 packages are lost).
The loss already occurres if I ping the second ip-adrress traceroute gives me (the first one after my pfsense).

The gateway overview of the pfsense shows me:

> Fiber (default)   185.*.*.*   185.*.*.*   3.771ms 3.06ms  19% Warning,
> Packetloss: 19%

The ISP says "everything is fine, the problem is your configuration".

Next week I will directly connect my notebook to the media converter and repeat the test, but at the moment, I have no physical access to this server.

What do you think? Sounds like configuration problem on pfsense, esx or broken media converter?
Is there a possibility to track these lost packets?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot guess about the configuration. Please edit your question to include the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As it is and with the very scarce information you provide, there's no way to tell where packets are lost.

You'll need to test the Internet link directly, with reduced complexity.

Potential points:

- ISP
- fiber link
- media converter
- cabling
- host NIC
- host configuration
- VM configuration
- guest configuration

Work your way from top to bottom and check where the problem first becomes visible. Note that host configurations and issues (2nd half of list) aren't on-topic here.

Comment: After directly connecting a PC to the media converter, the problem still exists (same packet loss on this PC). So the problem is on the ISP side. Media converter was replaced by a new one, had no effect.

Comment: Yes, looks like an ISP issue.